# Can we modify the area of any android application programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to change the application area in android. is it possible or not, if yes then can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "change the application area" and "modify the area of any android application programmatically" mean.

Comment: What is meaning of area here ?

Comment: post more precisely what do you want

Comment: example: if we open any application on android device then its occupy default area. but i want to modify that default area. suppose if we open facebook app on my device then is it possible to take half area of screen?

Comment: Sure, if you're running Android N and your app [has multi-window support](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html)

Comment: @Michael - Yes, I'm running Android N and my application is also multi-windows support. but we can do only for my apps. but i want to modify the  screen area for all android app's.

Comment: Well, as a user you can do that if you force multi-window support in the developer settings (though non-conforming apps may not behave well). But if you mean that you want to control this from your app, then I'm not aware of any way of doing that.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android N adds support for displaying more than one app at the same time. On handheld devices, two apps can run side-by-side or one-above-the-other in split-screen mode.

Refer : [Multi Window](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html)

Comment: this is the example of split screen. actually my question is how to manage area of all application in Android.